# doc and docx email validation working fine on local but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, email, ms-word

I am creating an email application where i am validating attached word and excel documents is valid or not.Its working fine on local system but when i am deploying the ddls on server it not working for word documents(doc and docx). for validation of word and excel docs, i write the below code-
 Note: I  installed MS office on server for reading of word document. For reading doc and docx i using microsoft interop refrence and its ddl deployed on server. but it is not working.

1- code for word file validation

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Word.Application application = new Word.Application();
                Word.Document document = application.Documents.Open(@"E:\Invalid.docx", Type.Missing, true);
                MessageBox.Show("Valid File");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

2- for validating the excel (xls and xlsx) documents i write the below code.I used introp excel for validation. it working fine local and on server.

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
+ "Data Source=E:\\Test.xls;"
+ "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";

            try
            {
                OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strExcelConn);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
                connExcel.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                connExcel.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

please help me why it is not working for doc and docx.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because that you are launching windowed application in session which is not windowed. Moreover IIS_USRS probably is not allowed to run MS Word.

I suggest to open doc files using interop. Than it will work